# BLE pairing/binding

Tags: android

I am developing an android app which include Low Energy Bluetooth(BLE) for communication of data. My app play role as clint . I want to Include pairing functionality but i could not able to find security manager Api in android. If anyone have any suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance..

Comment: Welcome to SO @Praveen. Please edit your post to show what research you have done so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you already have an arrayList of searched devices(`ArrayList<Bluetoothdevice> deviceScansionati`) you can select one of its and create a bond.

```
deviceScansionati.get(position).createBond();
```

Comment: you're welcome. Can you check me the answer with the green check, please.